# why box dblclick doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with the  box dblclick function it is not pass the page dblclick when i click on div with box class it do the page click function instead

my question is how can I make the double click on the div with box class ignore the double click function of page function?

this is my code in html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/organizer.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/organizer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the js code:

```
    var tempX=0;
    var tempY=0;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.box').dblclick(function() 
    {
        box2();
    });
    $('#page').dblclick(function()
    {
        tempX=0;
        tempY=0;
        box();
    });
});

function box()
{
    tempX = event.pageX-110;
    tempY = event.pageY-60;

    $('<div></div>').addClass('box').css({top:tempY,left:tempX}).appendTo($('#page'));

}

function box2()
{
    tempX = event.pageX-400;
    tempY = event.pageY-180;

    $('<div></div>').addClass('box2').css({top:tempY,left:tempX}).appendTo($('#page'));

}
```

this is the css code:

```
 #page
{
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;



}

.box
{   
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    z-index:10;
}
.box2
{   
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin:5px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Your `#page` element doesn't take place in HTML. You need position `absolute` instead of `relative` or put some text content in your `#page` element it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a **.box**, which is itself in **#page**, the events "bubble up", which means that the **#page** event will be fired. To avoid that, use `event.stopPropagation()`.

Also, you are binding actions to elements that do not exist yet, so they won't work unless you use **event delegation**:

`$(document).on('dblclick','.box',function(){...});`

**JS**

```
$(document).on('dblclick','.box',function(event) 
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        box2();
    });
$(document).on('dblclick','#page',function()
    {
        tempX=0;
        tempY=0;
        box();
    });
```

Also, for your **#page** to be visible, set it's position to **absolute**.

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: @user15337 I edited my answer, check the JS Fiddle Demo